# Android apps without marketplace

Tags: android

I want a know if it's possible to install a android application that I created but without passing by the market place, because the apps is for my company only. And the solution must also be legal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compile into .apk, send the file to everyone (in email) and use android to open the apk file and it will ask if you want to install it.

Moreover, make sure the settings in your phone allows unknown source installation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible and 100% legal. Just build the apk (using Eclipse with the plugin or the command line tools) and distribute it as you like.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an ATT phone, then you can do this easily by clicking "allow installations of 3rd party apps" or whatever that setting is called. You can then just put the .apk file onto your SD card and open it with a file explorer like astro.

If you have an ATT phone, you'll have to download the android sdk and use ADB to push the app onto your phone.

Comment: There is also the "Sideload Wonder Machine", which is a bundle of the portions of the SDK to allow loading of apps via USB by way of `adb`. This, at least, should be smaller and simpler to install than is the full SDK, though I have not tried it.

Comment: I don't have an ATT phone, so I don't know any of that stuff. Sounds like a much better solution than downloading the sdk though.